# HTTP::Server::Simple Won't install

Tags: perl, httpserver

Fails a test, don't know how to get around it.

```
#   Failed test 'Environment - REMOTE_ADDR'
#   at t/04cgi.t line 64.
#                   'HTTP/1.0 200 OK
# Content-Type: text/html
# Content-Length: 27
# 
# REMOTE_ADDR: 17x.x.x.x'
#     doesn't match '/REMOTE_ADDR: 127.0.0.1/'
t/04cgi.t .......... 19/23 # Looks like you failed 1 test of 23.
t/04cgi.t .......... Dubious, test returned 1 (wstat 256, 0x100)
Failed 1/23 subtests
```

Apparently an environmental variable is set to the VPS's host ip; not 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`force`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#The_force_and_the_fforce_pragma) the install step.

To find out why the test fails, step through the debugger. The interesting part is `HTTP::Server::Simple::lookup_localhost`. Perhaps your `/etc/hosts` file is frobnitzed.